# access to a class variable

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming, coffeescript

I'm trying to access to a class variable through an instance method through an eval (`Function`)

```
class Foo
  @classVariable = "helow"

class Bar extends Foo
  bar: -> (new Function("console.log(Foo.classVariable)")).call @
  baz: -> console.log(Foo.classVariable)

(new Bar()).baz()
(new Bar()).bar()
```

but method `bar` raise an error, telling me `ReferenceError: Foo is not defined`

Any advices ?
Is there another to access a class variable ?

Comment: What does "acceed" mean?

Comment: @Paul maybe "access" is the good word. English is not my native language

Comment: No worries, thanks for the clarification.  I edited the question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a function by passing a string to the `Function` constructor, that function can only see the global scope (see [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression)). If you wrote

```
class (window ? global).Foo
  ...
```

then your code would work. Alternatively, instead of using the `Function` constructor, just use `eval`:

```
bar: -> eval "console.log(Foo.classVariable);"
```

Comment: Thank you i will try your solution, when i'll be back to my home. I already tried using `eval`